# Using New-Object -Property to set properties of a nested class

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Lets say I define the following classes in C# inside a powershell script:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public class InnerClass {
    int a, b;
    public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
    public int B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
}
public class SomeClass {
    string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name= value; } }
    InnerClass numbers;
    public InnerClass Numbers { get { return numbers; } set { numbers = value; } }
}
"@
```

I can instantiate an instance of `InnerClass` like so:

```
New-Object InnerClass -Property  @{
    'A' = 1;
    'B' = 2;
}
```

However, if I want to instantiate `SomeClass` and set the properties for `InnerClass` in a similar manner, it fails.

```
New-Object SomeClass -Property @{
    'Name' = "Justin Dearing";
    Numbers = @{
        'A' = 1;
        'B' = 2;
    };
} ;

New-Object : The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Cha
nge the value, and then try again.
At line:20 char:11
+ New-Object <<<<  SomeClass -Property @{
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Object], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidValue,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb 
   jectCommand



Name    : Justin Dearing
Numbers :
```

Is there anyway to set `SomeClass`, including the properties of `Numbers` in one New-Object statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't directly but you can have the innerclass constructed inline with

```
New-Object SomeClass -Property @{
'Name' = "Justin Dearing";
'Numbers' = New-Object InnerClass -Property  @{
  'A' = 1;
  'B' = 2;
 }  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing like this I believe:

```
New-Object SomeClass -Property @{
     'Name' = "Justin Dearing";
     Numbers = New-Object InnerClass -Property  @{
                'A' = 1;
                'B' = 2;
            };
} ;
```